# NUnit and high amount of parallel tests

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, nunit

Is any fairly limit to run slow Selenium tests in parallel, which depends on limitation of .Net?

We are using .Net 4.7.1 and notice, that 30 parallel workers run faster then 100. Of course, it could be a problem of SUT, network and so on.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking? Is it why this happens? How to select best level? How to specify level of parallelism?

Comment: The question is about how to select the best level.

Comment: If it runs  fastest with 30, then use 30. For high degrees of parallelism, i.e. greater than the number of cores, there's no way to select except through experimentation.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I need reasons for my collogues, who want to run at 100+ simultaneously, having 8 test runs on same machine, and blaming just test environment, not .Net limitations.